# Magento : customer place order and not subscribe to newsletter subscription

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, onepage-checkout, newsletter

Using event and observer i have make auto subscription for customer but i want to do if customer has more than 2 order then customer should not auto subscribe to newsletter subscription.

Help me if you have any better suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: but when customer placed order for a first time then customer autosubscribe to newsletter subscription then why you want to customer not subscribe when customer placed two or more order? i think after placed one order , next time customer should not autosubscribe.

Comment: when customer already subscribed then why you subscribed customer again? can you please explain more your requirement?

Comment: i have 10 years old customer and condition is that if they have already order before this and his/her subscription status not subscribe with newsletter and now they order for second time so their subscription status should not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Create a module with name **STech_Autosubscription** like below:

**Step 1:**
Create file **STech_Autosubscription.xml** under:

> app/etc/modules/STech_Autosubscription.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <STech_Autosubscription>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </STech_Autosubscription>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2:**
Create file **config.xml** under:

> app/code/local/STech/Autosubscription/etc/config.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <STech_Autosubscription>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </STech_Autosubscription>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <autosubscription>
        <class>STech_Autosubscription_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>autosubscription_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </autosubscription>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        <observers>
          <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>autosubscription/observer</class>
            <method>autoSubscribe</method>
            <args></args>
          </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**
Create file **Observer.php** under:

> app/code/local/STech/Autosubscription/Model/Observer.php

with content:

```
<?php
class STech_Autosubscription_Model_Observer
{
    public function autoSubscribe(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerEmail = $order->getCustomerEmail();
        $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $customerEmail);
        if(count($orders) <= 2){
            $this->_autoSubscribe($customerEmail);
        }
    }

    protected function _autoSubscribe($email)
    {
        Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
    }    

}
```

Flush the cache and test.

Comment: Thanks Sukmar Gorai, i have made same module then also not get actually output.

Comment: @sarfaraj, can you please share your output/result/error occurred after using above module.?

Comment: @shashank, there is not any error but  when order completed the customer newsletter subscription check box checked automatic  and this is not right.

Comment: @Sarfaraj if you used the same code, then $this->_autoSubscribe($customerEmail); should be not executed but according to you it's execute.then you should  maintain logs so that you  can ensure what data comes

Answer (score 0):

i got your point.

use this sql query to get number of orders customer have

```
$result =   SELECT COUNT('customer_email') FROM  sales_order where customer_email = 'customer email address'; // this query give you no of record of order of customer
```

now check

```
if($result <= 2 ) {
    //here your autosubscrption code
}
```

**Try This, i hope it would be helped you**

Comment: thanks for reply , $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $email);
  $_orderCnt = $_orders->count(); //orders count  
  if ($_orderCnt == 1){
               // subscribe function
}
but not working if order >= 2 then also auto subscribe.

Comment: $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $email);
 $_orderCnt = $_orders->count(); //orders count 
if ($_orderCnt <= 2){       //this is your requirement
     // subscribe function
 }
**Change your if condition and make sure  $_orderCnt  gave correct value**

Comment: this variable give me correct ordered count value.

Comment: have you modified your **if condition**. try this **if($_orderCnt  <= 2){**

Comment: send your code here.

Comment: please check surajkumar gorai code same code i had written

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84051/discussion-between-balwant-and-sarfaraj).